# write music notations on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to write music notation and chords in a web page.

Is there any library (like Mathjax for math) available for this? If not, then is there any other way to achieve this with decent results?

Comment: I choosed pataluc's answer because, it do not require HTML5 or any JavaScript. Small and simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mathjax analog for lilypond](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318551/mathjax-analog-for-lilypond)

Comment: What's wrong with HTML5 and JavaScript? You did write "in a web page", didn't you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i think you could try with a music font, like these 2: http://www.fontspace.com/david-rakowski/lassus or http://www.fontspace.com/robert-allgeyer/musiqwik (there maybe others, i made a quick search...)

it's not perfect, but it could do the trick. You'll have to integrate the font on your website and get it working with the proper css rules...

Comment: It looks like an interesting idea. Doesn't allow for anything reasonably complex, but at least it's extremely easy to use.

Comment: that was my thought indeed..

Answer (score 29):

Look at this Javascript api for creating sheet music using html5 canvas.

http://www.vexflow.com/docs/tutorial.html

Example:

```
 <canvas width=700 height=100"></canvas>
```

UPDATED (18 March 2014)

And then:

```
var canvas = $("div.three div.a canvas")[0];
  var renderer = new Vex.Flow.Renderer(canvas,
    Vex.Flow.Renderer.Backends.CANVAS);

  var ctx = renderer.getContext();
  var stave = new Vex.Flow.Stave(10, 0, 500);

  // Add a treble clef
  stave.addClef("treble");
  stave.setContext(ctx).draw();

  var notes = [
    // Dotted eighth E##
    new Vex.Flow.StaveNote({ keys: ["e##/5"], duration: "8d" }).
      addAccidental(0, new Vex.Flow.Accidental("##")).addDotToAll(),

    // Sixteenth Eb
    new Vex.Flow.StaveNote({ keys: ["eb/5"], duration: "16" }).
      addAccidental(0, new Vex.Flow.Accidental("b")),

    // Half D
    new Vex.Flow.StaveNote({ keys: ["d/5"], duration: "h" }),

    // Quarter Cm#5
    new Vex.Flow.StaveNote({ keys: ["c/5", "eb/5", "g#/5"], duration: "q" }).
      addAccidental(1, new Vex.Flow.Accidental("b")).
      addAccidental(2, new Vex.Flow.Accidental("#"))
  ];

  // Helper function to justify and draw a 4/4 voice
  Vex.Flow.Formatter.FormatAndDraw(ctx, stave, notes);
```

This will produce:

[image: This]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Umm... that second snippet doesn't actually show how to add notes. It's just a repeat of the first snippet

Comment: that's a "pre-pre-pre-alpha" (quoted ^^) but it seems very powerful and interesting.

Comment: Sorry wrong part. but it's too long. You can see it yourself at the link I posted at the top of my answer.

Comment: I think this is a really awesome api. You can make the canvas as big or as small as you want. and the notes aren't difficult to add. Also a big plus, there's a good/clean tutorial for it.

Comment: And maybe it's just good to use it. there aren't a lot of people using this at the moemnt. and it looks like it's working fine even in the alpha state.

Comment: is there an option to play the music in midi ? I didn't find one in the doc

Answer (score 25):

Here are a few libraries with the supported formats:

- [VexFlow](http://www.vexflow.com) (own textual language called [VexTab](http://www.vexflow.com/vextab/))
- [AlphaTab](http://www.alphatab.net) ([GuitarPro](http://www.guitar-pro.com), own textual language called [alphaTex](http://demo.alphatab.net/old/))
- [Verovio](http://www.verovio.org/javascript.xhtml) ([MEI](http://music-encoding.org/), can import [MusicXML](http://www.musicxml.com/))
- [ABCjs](https://abcjs.net/) ([ABC](http://abcnotation.com))

Comment: I am the developer of AlphaTab. In the latest build (source on GitHub) we also support a JSON variant of the internal datamodel we use. This makes it more easy to store files in the database than GuitarPro Binary Files. MusicXML is on my roadmap.

Comment: HTML5 view link dead :|

Comment: Replaced with a link to another library.

Comment: I created an Observable library to embed ABC tunes in notebooks: https://beta.observablehq.com/@thsoft/abc

Answer (score 3):

There is some ASP.NET MVC API for music engraving: http://manufaktura-controls.com/
It renders notes to SVG or CANVAS format.

EDIT:
I recently released my music notation library as open source: http://musicengravingcontrols.com/
It has two web implementations: for ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core and one experimental implementation for Blazor 0.4.
The first two are server-side, the third is client-side (via WebAssembly).

Comment: This is a great project.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Lilypond](http://www.lilypond.org/) as the notation language, and I wrote small PHP script that parsed out the lilypond scripts out of a Markdown document and replaced them with the rendered PNG file.

You can have a look at the way [this Wordpress Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/scorerender/) does the job.

Answer (score 2):

I used the Lassus font as mentioned in one of the other Answers before. http://www.fonts2u.com/lassus.font - Download the @fontface version which includes the stylesheet to link it and a html document as an example.

I used mine as follows:

```
@font-face {font-family:"Lassus";
            src:url("LASSUS.eot?") format("eot"),url("LASSUS.woff")     format("woff"),url("LASSUS.ttf") format("truetype"),url("LASSUS.svg#Lassus") format("svg");
            font-weight:normal;
            font-style:normal;
}
```