# separate musical notes from an youtube video and display it using client-side technologies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube, youtube-api, audio

I would like to know if is possible to do the algorithm bellow by using some client-side technology ?

The algorithm would do:

1. Get the audio from YouTube, video will still be playing on the same page.
2. Separate the audio to separate the sound of the instruments that are playing. (Possible: [with server-side](http://www.elevayta.net/product13.htm))
3. Identify for the specific instrument which note is it playing. (Possible: [with server-side](http://www.sibelius.com/products/audioscore/ultimate.html))
4. Render the proper not for the instrument using this notation. (Possible: [write music notations on web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190131/write-music-notations-on-web-page))

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for the comment, do you know in which kind of community from stackoverflow should I do this kind of question ? I will move it to this question to other place.

Comment: You can keep it here if you add code and what effort you have tried. It's the code less questions SO closes. A Google and other investigation normally will tell you if you have a shot at it.

Comment: Well, there is no code on the question, but the question can be changed to: "I would like to know if is possible to do it with some client-side technology ?" I would like to know if it is even possible, I google it and didn't find this answer. Changing the question for this one will be less about opinion and more objective.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms?hl=fr) of the YouTube API

> PROHIBITATIONS
>
> - separate, isolate, or modify the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API
> - promote separately the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API
> - store copies of YouTube audiovisual content

For more information, check this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/MIADCvwmx_4).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would play on the same time the YouTube video is playing. 
Ok, it would separate the audio for analyzing it, but I think the main purpose of this condition was to avoid the person to use the YouTube services and don't show the ads.